# Finding in siblings subtree with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to find a tag in siblings subtree with BeautifulSoup? The scenario here is that I have already found a tag that I wanted, and I need to grab another tag that is in its sibling's subtree.

An equivalent xpath would be

```css
#mytag ~ div span
```

```css
#mytag ~ div span{
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="mytag"></div>
<span>nope</span>
<div>
  <span>foo bar</span>
</div>
```

I can find all siblings using `.find_next_siblings` but that doesn't search for subtrees. Is there a way that I can do it easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select()` which accept [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) expression to accomplish this easily :

```
mydiv.select("~ div span")
```

quick test :

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> raw = '''<div>
... <div id="mytag"></div>
... <span>nope</span>
... <div>
...   <span>foo bar</span>
... </div>
... </div>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, 'lxml')
>>> mydiv = soup.find("div", {"id": "mytag"})
>>> mydiv.select("~ div span")
[<span>foo bar</span>]
```

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know this is possible. I will see if it works as expected and get back to you.

Comment: `soup.select('#mytag ~ div span')` would have worked too, no?